# How to extract value from a nested json array?

Tags: json, spring-mvc

i have a json object which contains json data with a key. now i want to extract value from that json object like name, address etc and store them to variables.

**controller**

```
        json_arr = new JSONArray(j_str);
        int count = json_arr.length();

        json_o.put("user", json_arr);
```

**j_str contains following data**

```
[{"Bollywood":[{"actor":[{"name":"AA","gender":"Male"},{"name":"BB","gender":"Male"}]}]},{"Hollywood":[{"actor":[{"name":"CC","gender":"Male"},{"name":"DD","gender":"Male"}]}]}]
```

now it is converted to json object -- json_o ,, putting a key --- "user". now how can get a specific data such as 2nd actor name from hollywood. (i.e value DD). after then store that to a string.

Comment: your json is invalid. please validate your json string first using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.

Comment: @DibakarPaul  no.. its surely nice json string. i have checked it ur given site or u can check on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use Jackson to map the json string to a java object, and then extract that value as a variable.

Here is a quick guide on doing this with jackson: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: they have given a simple json. and that is also from a json file. mine is more complex. i want to get a specifec value from json. if you can help me with code then go ahead.

Comment: Jackson is very powerful, you can write custom serialisers/deserialisers to map incredibly complex json.  You asked a simple question and got a simple answer.  Asking someone to write your code for you without even bothering to try yourself is a good way to get downvoted.

Comment: lol.. @AdamSmith .. downvoted,, so what,, i am not here for Voting Competetion ...

Comment: No, it seems you're here to be lazy and ask people to do your work for you without even bothering to try out frameworks to solve the problem yourself.